# Python:: Converting a data from csv into data of type "str"

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

This is my first day in python.
I have a csv file like the below. [image]

Link to the file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlQo_tHSk1tGjlZYua8xoHSRQ4m6.

File name : toy.csv

```
id  text
1   hello world
2   hello foo world
3   hello my world
```

I have to write a code such that it takes the following format:

Required format:

```
'{"documents":[{"id":"1","text":"hello world"},{"id":"2","text":"hello foo world"},{"id":"three","text":"hello my world"},]}'
num_detect_langs = 1;
```

One way to directly hard code as follows:

```
input_texts = '{"documents":[{"id":"1","text":"hello world"},{"id":"2","text":"hello foo world"},{"id":"three","text":"hello my world"},]}'
```

Here the type of input texts would be "str"

However in practice this may not be possible as my input file can contain 1000s of records. I understand that we need to form a "for" loop kind of stuff so that 
it takes the required format. I dont know how to achieve this.

Can someone please help here.

Comment: having a look at this may help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: and this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your data is in some file like "data.csv" in your working directory. I am also assuming it is a *comma* separated list (you've only posted a picture which is extremely unhelpful). Anyway:

```
import csv
import json
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    input_text = {'documents': list(reader)}
input_text = json.dumps(input_text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

this does not exactly what you want yet but gets you pretty close:

```
import io
import json

# this is only to fake your input file...
file = io.StringIO('''id  text
1   hello world
2   hello foo world
3   hello my world
''')

# you would have to open your file:
# with open('filename', 'r') as file:
#     ...

lst = []
header = next(file)  # read and discard the header (id  text)
for line in file:
    splt = line[:-1].split(None, 1)
    lst.append({'id': splt[0], 'text': splt[1]})

print(json.dumps(lst))

# [{"id": "1", "text": "hello world"}, 
#  {"id": "2", "text": "hello foo world"},
#  {"id": "3", "text": "hello my world"}]
```

i am sure you will figure the rest out.

this uses only built-in functions. but seeing that you mention 'data frame' i guess you would like to use pandas...

Answer (score 1):

To convert the dataframe object say `df` you mentioned in the question to desired format you can do something like this:

```
d={}
d["Documents"] = df.to_dict(orient='records')    
print d
```

Output:

```
{'documents': [{'text': 'hello world', 'id': 1}, {'text': 'hello foo world', 'id': 2}, {'text': 'hello my world', 'id': 3}]}
```

Comment: Defining `d={"documents": []}` before the loop requires `n` lookups of the key "documents" just to append values. Not a good idea.

Comment: @MYGz - any idea why the text and id are swapped? Cant it be  like this  {"id":"1","text":"hello world"}. Id followed by text?

Comment: @Sijo Order is not preserved in Python dictionaries up until Python3.5. From Python3.6 upwards it's preserved.

Comment: @Harald You are right. Changed it. `df.to_dict()` can achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an input file called `data.txt`:

```
id  text
1   hello world
2   hello foo world
3   hello my world
```

Do this to create your desired JSON string:

```
import json

with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

first_line = lines[0]

id_header, text_header = first_line.split()
text_index = first_line.index(text_header)

documents = []

for line in lines[1:]:
    index = line.split()[0]
    text = line[text_index:]

    documents.append({
        id_header: index,
        text_header: text,
    })

result = {"documents": documents}

json_string = json.dumps(result)
print json_string
```

Comment: No it's not a file. He has a DataFrame object. Even I mistakenly considered it as a file at first.

Comment: Damn it. I have Pandas as an ignored tag because I know nothing of it, didn't even realize that the data frame here had a special meaning. Whoopsie.

Comment: Consider learning some basic Pandas. Data manipulation becomes much easier. Take a look when you have time: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Comment: And it's funny that on his first day in Python he is doing pandas :P. Maybe he is an `R` guy.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren - Thanks for the response.  As MYGz pointed out am an R guy. In R, once the data is read, it will be considered as data frame. Sorry for the confusion caused. However in the case above, I am loading the data from a csv file. Could you please let me know the line 
id_header, text_header = first_line.split() is correct? This throws me an error "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack".

Comment: @HaraldNordgren - the line "text_index = first_line.index(text_header)" also leads to an error --> "TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object". Could you please advise me whether am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Could edit your post to include the exact details of your input file?

Comment: @HaraldNordgren - modified the question. The data comes from a csv file. That is the data which i receive from CSV. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Please post the actual CSV file. Or at least the corresponding snippet if you want to keep the contents secret. There are libraries in Python for dealing with CSV files and those would probably be very helpful here.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren - i have added the snippet. I am not sure if this will be useful. Please let me know

Comment: @SijoK you've added a screenshot from some excel-like program which is the opposite of what was being asked for, that obfuscates your file **even more**.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Thanks for the suggestion. Here is the file loaded. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlQo_tHSk1tGjlZYua8xoHSRQ4m6.

Comment: File name is toy.csv